# EF6 Select from MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have an existing MySQL database with tables. I am creating a windows service which will fetch data from the MySql table `c2b2_callbacks` and pass the value to my DTO class.

Below is my select statement

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Callback>> GetCallbacks()
    {

        using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();
                //MySqlTransaction sqlTransaction = await conn.BeginTransactionAsync();

                using (M2AContext context = new M2AContext())
                {
                    //context.Database.UseTransaction(sqlTransaction);

                    // Error
                    IEnumerable<CallBack> transactions = await context.Transactions.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM oapi_test.c2b2_callbacks WHERE Status = 0 AND MSISDN REGEXP \'^([a-z]*[a-z]\\s*){3}([0-9]*[0-9]){3}([a-z]){1}$\';").ToListAsync(); 
                    return transactions;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //log
                Console.WriteLine($"Error {e.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is My `CallBack` class

```
 public class CallBack
{
    public string TransID { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransTime { get; set; }
    public string MSISDN { get; set; }

    public Int16 Status { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my context

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class M2AContext: DbContext
{
    public M2AContext(): base()
    {

    }

    public M2AContext(DbConnection connection, bool ownedconnection): base(connection, ownedconnection)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Callbacks> Transactions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the transactions but it fails at the `SELECT` statement and throws this error

```
{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

I have gone through [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) documentation and I don't know why there is this error.

This is the stack trace

```
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
at MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection connection)
at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest)
at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ExecuteSqlQueryAsync(String sql, Boolean asNoTracking, Nullable`1 streaming, Object[] parameters)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlSetQuery.GetAsyncEnumerator()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>.GetAsyncEnumerator()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ForEachAsync[T](IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToListAsync[T](IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToListAsync[T](IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery`1.ToListAsync()
at m2a.Repositories.Repository.<GetCallbacks>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\JNyingi\source\repos\m2a\Repositories\Repository.cs:line 38
```

Comment: does your query return any results when you run it manually?

Comment: Yes it does it returns a result as expected

Comment: if you move the call to `ToListAsync()` to the next line after return (like this `return transactions.ToListAsync()`) and set a breakpoint in the line w/ the query do you get the error? (if you step over is `transactions` null?)

Comment: You cant turn a class object to a linq query ... Note
`IEnumerable<Callback> transactions`

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `conn` when you create the `context`?

Comment: is it possible to post struture of `oapi_test.c2b2_callbacks` ?

Comment: The callback class is exactly as the columns of the table, c2b2_callbacks

Comment: I think the code wont compile your expecting `IEnumerable<MpesaTransaction>` but your returning `IEnumerable<CallBack>` as result.  Please include full details

Comment: @Eldho The error actually occurs on the select statement, that was a typo

Comment: How would EF know to bind c2b2_callbacks to CallBack I think you are missing a modelBuilder mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to provide a mapping otherwise EF won't know how to bind to the CallBack object

```cs
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

should be

```cs
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CallBack>("c2b2_callbacks");
    }
```